# List<String> always gives null value untill data is hardcoded

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am having a global variable :
`List<String> cheifComplaintList = new ArrayList<>();`

and a method : `fetchCheifComplaints()`

and the method is described as :

```
private void fetchCheifComplaints() {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            endpoints.ENDPOINT_GET_CHEIF_COMPLAINTS,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onResponseCheifComplaints: " + response);

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("complaints");

                        for (int i = 1; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "List: " + jsonArray.getString(i));
                            cheifComplaintList.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponseCheifComplaints: ", error);
        }
    })
```

but I am getting `cheifComplaintList = null` always.
But when I am setting values as `cheifComplaintList.add("Some value");` they work.

Json response is:

```
onResponseCheifComplaints: {"complaints":[""," Bad breath"," Bleeding gum","Senstivity"," Tooth ache","Wants to clean the teeth"]}
```

Comment: Where have you called the fetchCheifComplaints method?

Comment: in another method that is also defined in the same class

Comment: post JSON response as well and use GSON for data Mapping.!

Comment: check if you're getting any exception.

Comment: May be your jsonarray.getstring throws exception

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi posted.

Comment: @SripadRaj No i m not getting any exception

Comment: @ManiKumar I think fetchCheifComplaints is being called before cheifComplaintList is initialized
Try to put your initializition part in onCreate

Comment: @AbhayBohra i am initializing cheifComplaintList first and then i am calling other methods. and its in onCreate already.

Comment: What  is output of this line `Log.d(TAG, "List: " + jsonArray.getString(i));` in your logcat

Comment: please add your code where you have initialized and used `cheifComplaintList`

Comment: Solved it. I was populating cheifComplaintList before the completion of  onResponse of json request. Thanks for the answers

Comment: thats simple use GSON and map these on model class.!

Answer (score 0):

You may get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because you trying to insert data in `ArrayList` at 1 `index` instead of 0 `index`

Please see below code and take `int i=0;` in `for loop`

```
 try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("complaints");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "List: " + jsonArray.getString(i));
                        cheifComplaintList.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```